# Expected length of arc containing a point

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability, expected-value

You are given a circle $C$ of unit radius and a point $M$ on it. Now, three points are chosen at random on the circle $C$ which divides it into three arcs. What is the expected length of the part that contains $M$?

My doubt is whether we should consider $M$ **fixed** or not.

Comment: I am not too sure but it seems to be true as you can always rotate the circle to get $M$ at the top.

Comment: Assuming M can be rotated at the top of the circle, how do we drive the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may consider $M$ fixed without loss of generality. $M$ cuts the circle into a line, which we take as having length 1 (scaling to the real circumference of $2\pi$ will happen at the end). The three random points on $C$ are then random variables $U_1,U_2,U_3\sim U(0,1)$ and
$$E(\text{length of arc containing }M)=E(U_{(1)})+(1-E(U_{(3)}))=E(\mathrm B(1,3+1-1))+1-E(\mathrm B(3,3+1-3))=E(\mathrm B(1,3))+1-E(\mathrm B(3,1))=\frac14+1-\frac34=\frac12$$
where $U_{(i)}$ are order statistics and $\mathrm B$ is the beta function. Thus, on the unit circle, the expected length of the segment containing $M$ is $\frac12\cdot2\pi=\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! very good explaination.